# Are epicanthic folds a dominant trait?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics, hybridization

My state (Tripura) originally had a mostly mongoloid-feature-possessing population (ethnic group: Tripuri). Recently a large number of non-mongoloid people (ethnic group: Bengali) have migrated to Tripura.
Assuming that reproductive barriers are not present between these two subpopulations in future, are epicanthic folds likely to be a prominent feature of the new hybridized population?

I've found some non-scientific discussions [here](http://Re:https://www.reddit.com/r/hapas/comments/4koung/til_almond_shaped_eyes_are_a_dominant_trait_in/) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-typical-east-Asian-eyes-with-epicanthic-folds-fatter-upper-lids-and-flatter-upper-noses-the-result-of-a-genetic-bottleneck-or-natural-selection-in-their-environment).

In [this newspaper article](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1985-10-13/news/8503100141_1_fold-asians-eyes), an anthropologist is cited as saying the following:

> Poirier attributes the fold to pleiotropic genes-**-single genes** that control more than one characteristic or function--but he has no explanation for its origin

Comment: This is an interesting question. What did you find when you googled this question? Please show us your research results. Thanks!

Comment: @anongoodnurse, There were several sites where I found answers which are not backed by research  and no genetic rationale but by everyday observation.So I didn't put them in question.

Comment: @ItachíUchiha You can link those sites anyway stating that you don't know whether the sources can be trusted. These sources may always help one to answer.

Comment: I did some preliminary searches but could find nothing about the genetics of epicanthal folds in normal people. The only references I could find were about epicanthal folds in a variety of genetic disorders. Sorry. :(

Comment: @anongoodnurse,please don't be sorry.Thanks a lot for your efforts. ^_^